# Why a mapped key in vim does not work in netrw?

Tags: vim, netrw

While exploring with `netrw`, you can hit `t` to open the directory in a new tab.

But if I do `:map v t`, then `v` will open the directory in a split window, not a tab.

Same if I do `:map v :normal t<CR>`

Why does this happen?  How can I accomplish such a map?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Duh.

`netrw` already has `v` mapped to split to a new window.

If I `map K`, this works.